# Lambda using outer connection variable inside forEach

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a connection object which is created once and used inside forEach.
Unable to use the connection object in finally as it is final without the initial value to be used inside forEach.

```
final Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = db.createConnection();

            final Map<String, String> dataMap = adminClient.list().values();

            dataMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {

                // Need to use connection object here ...
                // Unable to use the connection if it is not final and to make it final, not initializing it to null  ...
            });

        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            // Unable to use the connection here if it is not initialized to null ...
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
```

Is there any other better way?

Comment: you can use it without any hustle if its *effectively final*.

Comment: try with resources instead of finally?

Comment: @Naman - Eclipse shows error when i use it in finally without initializing it.

Comment: @David, What if i need to call a custom close methos, like close(timeout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) which exists since Java 7:

```
try(Connection connection = db.createConnection()) {
    final Map<String, String> dataMap = adminClient.list().values();
    dataMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        // use connection object here ...
    });
 }
 catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // replace with real handling later
 }
```

Since this eliminates the need to call `close` manually, you don’t have to preinitialize the variable with `null`. As a bonus, it can handle exceptions thrown in the `close` method correctly.

Even if your close operation is not an `AutoClosable.close()`, it can easily get adapted:

```
try {
    Connection connection = db.createConnection();
    try(AutoCloseable c = () -> connection.close(timeout)) {
        final Map<String, String> dataMap = adminClient.list().values();
        dataMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            // use connection object here ...
        });
    }
}
catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // replace with real handling later
}
```

and if you insist on your original `finally` logic:

```
try {
    Connection connection = db.createConnection();
    try {
        final Map<String, String> dataMap = adminClient.list().values();
        dataMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            // use connection object here ...
        });
    }
    finally {
        if(connection != null) connection.close(timeout);
    }
}
catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // replace with real handling later
}
```

Comment: What is i need to call a cutom close method. Like, close(timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Generally uninitialized variables are not supposed to read/compared. It also depends on the language of use and in this case java doesn't allow these operation on uninitialized variable.

There is a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076639/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-java). Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these changes will be help.

```java
Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = db.createConnection();
           final Connection theConnection = connection;

            final Map<String, String> dataMap = adminClient.list().values();

            dataMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                //use theConnection 

            });

        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            // Unable to use the connection here if it is not initialized to null ...
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
```